# How do you document JSDoc with mixed parameter type?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How do I document a method in JavaScript using **JSDoc** when the parameter type can be mixed?

I have method on a Dialog object where I can show HTML or my own Viewable objects. The method JSDoc looks like this:

```
/**
 * Can pass in viewable object, or some HTML element
 *
 * @param viewable viewable {Viewable} or HTML element {HTMLElement} or String {string}
 * @param {Boolean} cancelable is cancellable
 * @param title string or data object of String and Id {Title:String, Id:String} for setting HTML id value
 * @param {Array} actions array of functions actions display buttons on the bottom connecting to the passed in functions
 * @param {String} size mode. Can be mini,small,medium,large,maxi. Or of type {width:number, height:number}
 * @param {Number} zindex starting z-order. Note: first level dialog = 10,11,12, second level dialog 13,14,15 etc.
 */
Dialog.showElement = function(viewable, cancelable, title, actions, mode, zindex){
..
}
```

Because JS doesn't allow method overloading, I need to create these types of methods, where a parameter in a method can be two disparate types. Is there a way to document this in JSDoc, or can JSDoc only let you document a param with one type?

Also how would you document a paramater of type `{Title:String, Id:String}`? That is, an object passed in that is not of a type. Quasi, a JSON object.

Comment: This might not be part of the original JSDoc specification (I don't know), but have a look at this article which explains how to annotate JS for the Google Closure compiler: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types. It also has an example for "record types".

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use the `|` separator to specify multiple types in the method type signature:

```
/**
 * Some method
 * @param {Object|string|number} param The parameter.
 * @returns {Object|string|number} The modified param.
 */
function doSomething(param) {
    return etc..
};
```

Comment: but what about my {Title:String, Id:String} thing. Can I only document that as {Object} ?

Comment: so if I had that, and a string, would I document it like @param {String|{title: String, id: Object}} param ?

Comment: @OliverWatkins For objects, you can do the following `@param {object|string} obj` `@param {string} obj.a` `@param {string} obj.b`

Comment: @flavian Do you have references for your example? The official docs i could ever find so far require parentheses for this (see my answer below) - thus i believe this answer is formally wrong...

Answer (score 11):

[Google Closure Compiler Docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#unions) recommend the following form - which looks official as it is the same as found on [usejsdoc.org](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html):

```
/**
 * Some method
 * @param {(Object|string|number)} param The parameter.
 * @returns {(Object|undefined)} The modified param.
 */
function doSomething(param) {
    return etc..
};
```

To cite the above linked closure compiler docs:

> Note the parentheses, which are required.